# GitHub post-receive hook flow

Tags: web-applications, web-deployment, githooks

I have a repo on GitHub (Enterprise, for what that's worth) that I use for my app. I also have this app deployed on a development server on the same network. I've done some reading on Git hooks, and I've registered my dev server's URL in the WebHooks section of the repo on GitHub. However, I do not know how to set up a receive trigger, that every time commits are pushed to the repo, I want the server to receive the JSON data from the POST, update the web app repo (the web app is also under Git control) with the data, and restart some services.

How can I do the above mentioned in the simplest and easiest way possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? Do you still need an answer?